# Use one page design for website with a detailed "request a quote" form?

Tags: website-design, forms

One page website design seems to be the popular trend nowadays based on emerging websites and articles online. [[1](http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/design/8-reasons-why-pageless-design-is-the-future-of-the-web)][[2](http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/the-science-behind-a-single-page-website/)]

But should one go for one page website design for a website that has a long request-a-quote form to generate leads? The website itself will be based on providing one kind of service. So I guess one page style works best for websites related to one or two topics.

More specifically the request-a-quote form has multiple steps in a wizard format with many fields. The form would have server side validation so that invalid data is not entered.

In that case does it make sense to use the one-page-style website? I guess it doesn't make sense if the form will need to be navigated to a page or two? Especially since I intend to use [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) with Wordpress.

Comment: What value does a one page site bring to your project? If you can answer that, then there's your answer.

Comment: Well, might not go with OPW design since the request quotation form will dynamically grow with more fields depending on input causing leaking to other fixed sections of the one page website. Does it make sense to have the informative part of the website to be in one page style and the form part to be in a separate page?

Comment: Unless I put the form in the last section of the one page website. Then the form length can growth without leaking into other sections? But not sure if allowing the length to grow within the one page is good idea/design?

Comment: Again, what do you perceive is the benefit of a one page site? There's really no general way to answer this. It's all going to depend on the particularities of your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one page websites or SPAs (web apps) are very popular nowadays, they boost engagement and transmit the message faster to the user.

The problem with them is **SEO**, which is tricky to implement because of the Javascript used to manipulate the transitions and effects between sections and different effects and animations on the page. As you might know spiders  have limited capabilities for js execution and reading of the content, meaning that your message cannot be displayed in SERP and you will have to work harder on your Social Media optimization.

Building a web application with one page functionality it's your best choice, there are many open source frameworks that are making the web development process very fast and solve the above problems with content reading, scripts compression, etc.

To solve your form problem you will need to take a look at AngularJS , you can easily implement something like [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/M03tYgtfqNH09U4x5pHC/preview) in your website.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Clotaire. Do you have any evidence to support your assertion that one page sites "`are very popular nowadays, they boost engagement and transmit the message faster to the user`"? At the moment, it reads as opinion.

Comment: It is said that it takes 8 seconds to engage your visitors with your website/product. By using a One Page design you can easily tell a story about your service, it's intuitive and help with conversion rates, decreases the bounce rate, scaling well on any device. I like http://www.awwwards.com for inspiration. Read more here about OPW: http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/design/8-reasons-why-pageless-design-is-the-future-of-the-web

Comment: That is true. So I think AJAX based posting is possible with Gravity Forms. But not sure if we can do form validation with AJAX post in Gravity Forms. Any thoughts?

Comment: There's nothing more/less intuitive between one page site and a 100 page site. It's all in the design and implementation. Both can be good options.

Comment: There's also no reason a OPW can't be SEO friendly either. In otherwords, it's all about the specifics of implementation--not the number of pages the site has.

Comment: True. But this seems more convincing to avoid OPW http://www.web-savvy-marketing.com/2013/07/one-page-websites-templates/ if possible, especially for websites catering to niche service?